# how to scrape reddit using csv of subreddits and keywords (praw, python)

Tags: python, for-loop, praw

I've used the following code before and it worked, but I keep getting a BadRequest: received 400 HTTP response on the for loop. I think it's the "for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).search(i, limit=7):" because when I comment that out, I can print the subs and keywords. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The earlier part of the code, prior to the for loop, is below too for context.

```
for subreddit, keyword in diss_data_dict.items():
for i in keyword:
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).search(i, limit=7):
            print(subreddit, ":", i)
            diss_output_dict["id"].append(submission.id)
            diss_output_dict["subreddit"].append(submission.subreddit)
            diss_output_dict["created_utc"].append(submission.created_utc)
            diss_output_dict["title"].append(submission.title)
            diss_output_dict["url"].append(submission.url)
            diss_output_dict["num_comments"].append(submission.num_comments)
            diss_output_dict["upvote_ratio"].append(submission.upvote_ratio)
            diss_output_dict["score"].append(submission.score)
```

---

```
diss_data= pd.read_csv('./Scraper/diss_data.csv', sep = ',', usecols= ['subreddit', 'keyword'])

diss_data_dict={k: g["keyword"].tolist() 
              for k,g in diss_data.groupby("subreddit")}

column_names = ["id", "created_utc", "title", "name","num_comments", "upvote_ratio", "score"]

diss_output_dict = { "id":[], \
            "subreddit":[], \
            "created_utc":[], \
            "title":[], \
           "url":[], \
           "num_comments": [], \
           "upvote_ratio":[], \
           "score":[]}
```